# moving and rotating view in android

Tags: android, animation

I'm using this code to moving view from x Position to another x Position :

```
int xStart=100,xEnd=500;
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", xStart, xEnd);
objectAnimator.setDuration(duration);
objectAnimator.start();
```

but i need moving and rotating .

how can Rotate and move the view together ?

It is possible ?

Comment: see `AnimatorSet`or `ViewPropertyAnimator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` to animate any property of a View- essentially any property with `set___()` and `get___()` methods.

For rotation, you can use `"rotation"`, `"rotationX"`, and `"rotationY"` as appropriate.

It sounds like you already have translation working correctly, so I'm not sure what else you are looking for in "moving" the View.

To play multiple animations together, you can use an [`AnimatorSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html). To move and rotate at the same time, you might do this:

```
AnimatorSet animations = new AnimatorSet();
ObjectAnimator translationAnim= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100, 500);
ObjectAnimator rotationAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotation", 0, 90);
animations.play(rotationAnim).with(translationAnim);
animations.start();
```

For more information see [the Property Animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html).